# Как при парсере создать динамическую ссылку в python

Tags: python, парсер

Помогите с парсером. Есть URL с адресом, как реализовать в моем коде динамическое изменение https://www.eldorado.ru/c/televizory/?sort=-date_create на [https://www.eldorado.ru/c/{словарь](https://www.eldorado.ru/c/%7B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C) с категориями}/?sort=-date_create

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests

CSV = 'cars.csv'
HOST = 'https://www.eldorado.ru'
URL = 'https://www.eldorado.ru/c/televizory/?sort=-date_create' 
HEADERS = {  
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36'
}

def get_html(url, params=''):  
  r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params) 
  return r 



def get_content(html):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser') 
  items = soup.find_all('li', class_='ListingProductCardList_productCardListingWrapper__3-o9i') 
  cars = [] 

  for item in items: 
      try:

          cars.append({ 
              'title': item.find('a', class_='ListingProductCardList_productCardListingLink__1JIMi').get_text(strip=type),  
              'link': HOST + item.find('a', class_='ListingProductCardList_productCardListingLink__1JIMi').get('href'),
              'cash': item.find('span', class_='PriceBlock_buyBoxPrice__3QGyj PriceBlock_buyBoxPriceStyled__29J_G').get_text(strip=type), 
              'img': item.find('a', class_='ListingProductCardList_productCardListingImageContainer__FqE33').find('img').get('src') 

          })
      except:
          pass
  # print(cars) 
  return cars

def save_doc(items, path):
  with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
      writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
      writer.writerow(['Название продукта', 'ссылка', 'цена', 'картинка'])
      for item in items:
          writer.writerow([item['title'], item['link'], item['cash'], item['img']])

def parser():
  PAGINATION = input('Укажите номер страници для парсинга')
  PAGINATION = int(PAGINATION.strip())
  html = get_html(URL) 
  if html.status_code == 200: 
      cars = []
      for page in range(1, PAGINATION + 1):
          print(f'Парсим страницу: {page}')
          html = get_html(URL, params={'page': page})
          cars.extend(get_content(html.text))
          save_doc(cars, CSV)
      pass

      

  else:
      print('Ошибка')
```

Comment: Спарсить меню, составить список категорий и перебирать его, очевидно?...

Comment: Не могу применить это, а точнее описать в коде